# Clearing .png files from a Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In my Xcode project, i added a bunch of images to use. I need to change out the images so i removed them from the project and deleted them from the folder structure. They should be gone, right?

No.  when i launch the program, the images are still being used. I did a search on my computer for the file name and only found it in the code

(i used a constants file and put the file names into  strings:

```
NSString * const PRESET_LIGHT_GRAY = @"preset-rect-16.png";
NSString * const PRESET_ASH_GRAY = @"preset-rect-17.png";
```

and this is the only place on my mac that i find the file name).

there is no file on my mac named "preset-rect-16.png" yet Xcode is still using the image.

where is Xcode getting the images? are they stored somewhere else in the project? are they saved in the simulator somewhere?

/puzzled

Comment: You DID remove the Build from the Builds folder right? Also, performed a Clean All?

Comment: I did Clean All. i'm not sure about the build. my project does not have a builds folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go here. Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data

[image]

Wherever your Derived Data Folder is, delete Build for this Project and then run again. Resetting the Simulator is also recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The images may still be referenced in your target build phases under copy bundle resources.  If so delete the references there as well.

Comment: i do not see them in there. when i removed them from the project, i removed the references. and then went and deleted them in the folder i had them in

Comment: try command+shift+f that will do a project wide search, if the image is referenced in code that will find it.  It's worth noting that if the image is set in a xib, that will NOT be found.  Search doesn't go through xibs.

Comment: yep, did a search like that. the only hits are in my constants.m file. also, i'm using storyboards and where only ever added the images through code.

Comment: Since it's no where to be found in code or xibs the derived app data has to be caching it.  Looks like mayuur's solution is what you need.